# Access store from service (or where I should be accessing the store)?

Tags: react-redux

I'm only a few days in (transitioning from Ember) so please pardon my ignorance.

I have an array of object (profileaccounts) in my store.
I have many different components which are connected to the store and have code like below, sometimes the user is the person logged in, sometimes its a user that is being passed into the component (when someone looks at someone else's profile)

```
componentDidMount() {
    let user = this.props.user;
    let account = this.props.profiles.find(function (prof) { return prof.profile.id === user.id });
    if (account == null) {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.getProfile(user.id));
    }
}
```

This completely works but I don't want this code replicated over and over again. My gut feeling is that I should always call `.getProfile(user.id)` and its the job of the actions to determine if the data exist in the local cache (store) or does it needs to be added. If it needs to be added, add it, then either way return it.
Alternatively, maybe the user service (which represents the API and is called by the actions to populate the profiles) is supposed to look locally before it calls the API. Regardless, I don't know how (or if I should) to access the store from the actions or service, only from the connected component.

I haven't seen this scenario in any of the guides I've read about redux/react, so if anyone can include a resource to where I should be looking I'd appreciate it. If I'm totally going about this the wrong way, I'd be happy to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redux-thunk to access state inside the action
link to thunk: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

The code would be like this:

```
function incrementIfOdd() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { counter } = getState();

    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch(increment());
  };
}
```

Using thunk you'll be able to access state inside the action.

Your approach sounds good...You'll start with dispatching an action "dispatch(getProfile(userId))" then inside the action you'll do whatever you want and when you finally have the data you want to put in the store dispatch another action "dispatch(storeUserProfile(profile))" which will put the data in the store via reducer.

Comment: Great, thank you, I really felt like I was close and just needed a bit more to understand how to get to where I wanted.  I appreciate the code sample as well as the reference to dispatching to another action that will store the userprofile.